# Exponential of commuting matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

I want to show that for two commuting matrices, say $A$ and $B$, we have $e^{A+B}=e^Ae^B.$

So far I have 
\begin{align*}
e^{A+B}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(A+B)^k \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} A^jB^{k-j} \\ 
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^k\frac{A^jB^{k-j}}{(k-j)!j!}
\end{align*}

I don't really know where to go now though. What do I need to do next?

Comment: Factor the final expression

Comment: Talking of _numbers_, we can be pretty sure that $e^{x+y}=e^x\cdot e^y$. Rewrite this in terms of series, and you'll have what you want.

Comment: What you have written is the Cauchy product of series $e^A$ and $e^B$.

Comment: Duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/370817).

Answer (score 2):

In the last expression, permute the sums in order to obtain

$$\sum _{j=0} ^\infty \sum _{k=j} ^\infty \frac {A^j B^{k-j}} {(k-j)! j!}$$

and finally make the change of summation variable $m = k-j$ to obtain

$$\sum _{j=0} ^\infty \sum _{m=0} ^\infty \frac {A^j B^m} {m! j!}$$

which is easily seen to be

$$\sum _{j=0} ^\infty \frac {A^j} {j!} \sum _{m=0} ^\infty \frac {B^m} {m!} = \Bbb e ^A \Bbb e ^B.$$

Alternatively, given that $A$ and $B$ commute, there is a basis in which both are diagonal, and working in this basis makes computations really easy. Try it!

Comment: Well working in a diagonal basis still requires the corresponding proof for numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by 'permute the sums...'?

Comment: @sksks52: I meant to interchange the order of summation: take the inner sum to the front, and put the outer sum inside.

Comment: why is the sum suddenly up to infinity? Newton's binom says its up to the power, so up to K,
permuting m=k-j only makes the counting go backward, but still only up to k..

please elaborate