# If $fg=gf$ show that $\exp(f+g) = \exp(f)\exp(g)$.

Tags: analysis, exponential-function, banach-spaces

This question is from Differential calculus by Henri Cartan:

Suppose that $fg = gf$ for $f,g\in L(E,E)$ where $E$ is a banach space and $\exp(f) = \displaystyle{\sum_{n\geq0} \frac{f^n}{n!}}$.
Show that $\exp(f+g)=\exp(f)\exp(g)$.

I am learning this on my own, which is why I'm so confused. Would someone please give me a hint?

Comment: Use the binomial formula for $(f+g)^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PaulichenT mentioned this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3943347/proving-exp-t-s-exp-t-exp-s-exp-s-exp-t-for-t-s-in-mathc) can help you, but I would like to give a different answer. We have that
\begin{align*}
\exp(f) \exp(g) &= \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^n}{n!}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{g^n}{n!}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n
\end{align*}
When
\begin{align*}
c_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\frac{g^k}{k!}\\[2mm]
&=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}f^{n-k}g^k\\[2mm]
&=\frac{1}{n!}(f+g)^n
\end{align*}
thus
\begin{align*}
\exp(f) \exp(g) &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(f+g)^n}{n!}=\exp(f+g)
\end{align*}

Comment: So it seems like there was no need for the condition $fg=gf$ ,right?

Comment: @Mina Is so necessary, think about this $(f+g)^2=(f+g)(f+g)=f^2+\color{red}{fg+gf}+g^2=f^2+2fg+g^2$.

Comment: Oh, right. So it was used in $c_n$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do we need to prove that we can use Cauchy product for Banach space?