Proof that $e^{(A_1+A_2)t}=e^{A_1 t} e^{A_2 t}$ if $Α_1Α_2=Α_2 Α_1$.
I want to prove that  $e^{(A_1+A_2)t}=e^{A_1 t} e^{A_2 t}$  if $Α_1Α_2=Α_2 Α_1$.
I started using Taylor series for $A_1$ and $A_2$ but I cannot find anything to continue. Any ideas?

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/370817/42969
